# ufw deny not works, but iptables is working

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, ufw

I want to use ufw and fail2ban to block portscan. 
After I setup them, fail2ban showed some IP were blocked, but actually not. 
I located problem to ufw, because fail2ban does ban the ip who want to crack ssh .

#### My testing

ifconfig result:(maybe helpful? I hide the real ip address)

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:15111490 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:15111490 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:1089923226 (1.0 GB)  TX bytes:1089923226 (1.0 GB)

venet0    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:127.0.0.2  P-t-P:127.0.0.2  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255
          inet6 addr: xxxxxxxxxxxxx/128 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:325172 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:720857 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:114732548 (114.7 MB)  TX bytes:196756412 (196.7 MB)

venet0:0  Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:xxxxxxxxxx  P-t-P:xxxxxxxxxx  Bcast:xxxxxxxxxx  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

block port 8923

```
ufw deny 8923
ufw deny out 8923
```

Run `ufw status verbose`:

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), deny (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
8923                       DENY IN     Anywhere
8923 (v6)                  DENY IN     Anywhere (v6)

8923                       DENY OUT    Anywhere
8923 (v6)                  DENY OUT    Anywhere (v6)
```

Run `iptables -L`:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
f2b-sshd   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports 29240
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:29240
ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-before-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-reject-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-track-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-before-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-reject-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-track-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:29240
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:29240
ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-before-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-reject-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-track-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

....

Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:8923
DROP       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:8923

Chain ufw-user-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:8923
DROP       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:8923
```

I run a website on 8923, but `curl myhost:8923` still can get the `index.html`.

My vps is openvz ubuntu 14.04, host is redhat kernel 2.6 and I get this article https://blog.kylemanna.com/linux/ufw-vps/

It says 2.6 openvz may have some problem(but my machine doesn't get warning message by  `/lib/ufw/ufw-init force-reload`) . Though I tried that config, neither work.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should know that openvz is poorly supported in Ubuntu. Ubuntu uses LXC (for better or worse). If you want to use openvz I highly advise you use a .rpm system as the kernel patch is written for a RHEL/Fedora kernel and may or may not have issues on debian/ubuntu kernels.

To some extent openvz is depreciated on Debian/Ubuntu hosts.

Second how do you know iptables is working ?

Third, if iptables works, I would use iptables rather then UFW.

If you need help with UFW / iptables you need to post all your rules and any additional information you can give me after reading my blog pages.

See http://blog.bodhizazen.com/linux/how-to-use-ufw-in-openvz-templates/

http://blog.bodhizazen.com/linux/proxmox-using-iptables-in-openvz-guests/

What host OS? Do you have root access on the host ?

What kernel are you running ? Which openvz patch - https://wiki.openvz.org/Download/kernel

Comment: 1. host OS is `Red Hat Enterprise 2.6.32 kernel`, I can't access it. 2. iptables  is working because fail2ban's `ssh jail` does work

Comment: Did you apply the patch - https://gist.github.com/kylemanna/5889836

Comment: Yeah, I have already tried that(https://blog.kylemanna.com/linux/ufw-vps/) before post this question

Comment: If that patch does not work you will need to use iptables until you debug ufw. Either that or start looking through the ufw rules for any other changes you need to make.

Comment: I personally like to use `ufw` with `iptables` because of how easy it is to change settings.

Comment: If you understand the ufw syntax iptables is trivial. Install iptables-persistent to preserve rules. `sudo iptables -A INPUT --dport 8923 -j REJECT` and `sudo iptables -D INPUT --dport 8923 -j REJECT`. looks simple enough to me. If you used standart ports like you are supposed to `sudo iptables -A INPUT --dport http -j ACCEPT` syntax is very similar to ufw.